# Image Modification in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, svg

I wish to add a filter that will make the `<image>` a certain color. The origial color is, for example, blue. During runtime, I wish for the user to be able to change the color of the parts in the `<image>`.

Is there a way of changing the color taint of an image during runtime? I know of using `filter` in embedded style

```
style={{filter: "blur(5px)}}
```

but is there a method of changing the rgba values into a color taint with huerotate, opacity, grayscale..etc?

```
function change(rgbaValues): {huerotate, saturation, etc}
```

pseudo-React code; do not take literally.

Comment: There is a lot that you can do with just CSS styling, but for the really advanced stuff you'll want to use the HTML `canvas` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will definitely use a canvas in the future. The question at hand is about inserting an rgba value and returning the filter values to taint an image that color though.